# Can there be 3CTAs at one place with equal weightage?

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, human-interface-guideline

On the checkout screen there are 3 CTAs,

1. simple checkout
2. Payment with debit card
3. Buy now pay later

All three with equal weightage of primary CTA.

Is it the right way?

Comment: Without any visual examples, the answers to this question are: yes, no, and maybe.

Answer (score 1):

**Multiple CTAs is not good design**

The idea of a prominent CTA button is that the user knows exactly what to do next. If you provide multiple CTAs with the same prominence/weight, you offload it to the user which action is the most preferable.

Ask yourself, what would 80% of your users like to do on this screen? Then style that button as the primary CTA and the rest as secondary.

Alternatively, if there is no clear preference, you can also style your payment options as a selection (radiobuttons) with a call to action (Pay).

[image]